# How do I join 2 cylinders in any given situation?

Tags: modeling

How do I join 2 cylinders in any given situation for smooth beveling and proper quad modelling? What is the rule for number of sides both cylinders should have? And should those number of sides be same or different in those cylinders?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Your question is way to general for an answer. How did you arrive at your first screenshot? For this case, you could get a specialised answer.

Comment: I joined (boolean) 2 cylinders with 8 and 5 sides and then beveled it. But it is not giving proper shape while subdividing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not one unique solution, in the case you show you could begin with a 16 and a 8 vertex cylinder, boolean them:

[image]

Rework the topology:

[image]

Bevel the edges:

[image]

Rework again:

[image]

Result with a *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]

Previous answer: create a 16x8 UV sphere that you cut and extrude:

[image]

Then select 4x3 faces and inset:

[image]

Right click > *LoopTools > Circle*:

[image]

Extrude:

[image]

Bevel:

[image]

Comment: I may have given the wrong impression. I wanted the top to be flat (of the big cylinder) and it is only after adding subdiv i get that tomb like shape which is undesired.

Comment: Although this has given me the general idea to subdivide the top of the big cylinder first and then extrude the circular shape for the small cylinder.

Comment: I've edited with a flat top, I hope it helps

Comment: Thank you. This helps a lot. Much appreciated.